# compress ASP.NET MVC component

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using IIS 5.1.I nees to js,css and view page.How should i do this.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

To compress JS and CSS, you use [Yahoo Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
To compress server response, use httpmodule. check this  [HTTP Compression Module](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/httpcompression.aspx).